# creating a new copy of a python class each time it's called

Tags: python, class, oop

I need some guidance on how to set this up correctly for what I'm trying to do.
I have a class called Attribute Block which I'll then use to create 3 or 4 Attribute block Objects. As seen below...

```
class AttributeBlock():
    def __init__(self, key, label, isClosed, isRequired, attributes):
        self.key = key
        self.label = label
        self.isClosed = isClosed
        self.isRequired = isRequired
        self.attributes = attributes if attributes is not None else {}
```

3 attributeBlock objects

```
AttributeBlock(
    key="Sphere",
    isRequired=True,
    attributes=[
        ''' Other class objects '''
        BoolProperty("ishidden", False, "Hidden"),
    ]
)

AttributeBlock(
    key="Box",
    isRequired=True,
    attributes=[
        ''' Other class objects '''
        BoolProperty("ishidden", True, "Hidden"),
    ]
)

AttributeBlock(
    key="Circle",
    isRequired=False,
    attributes=[
        ''' Other class objects '''
        BoolProperty("ishidden", True, "Hidden"),
    ]
)
```

What I then want to do is be able to add one of these AttributeBlocks to an Object, making sure when it's added, its a new instance of the AttributeBlock so its sub attribute objects are new instances.

This is the object I will add my attribute blocks to.

```
class ToyBox():
    def __init__(self, name="", attributes=[]):
        self.name = name
        self.attributes = attributes[:]

newToyBox = ToyBox()
newToyBox.name = "Jimmy"
```

**pseudo code**

```
def add_attribute_block(toybox = None, key = "" ):
    if an AttributeBlock with the matching key exists:
        add it to toybox.attributes

add_attribute_block( newToyBox, "Box" )

print newToyBox
>>
ToyBox
name="Jimmy"
attributes=[
    AttributeBlock(
        key="Box",
        isRequired=True,
        attributes=[
            BoolProperty("ishidden", True, "Hidden"),
        ]
    ),
    AttributeBlock(
        key="Sphere",
        isRequired=True,
        attributes=[
            BoolProperty("ishidden", True, "Hidden"),
        ]
    )
]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to automatically keep track of all created `AttributeBlock`objects, you could use a class attribute:

```
class AttributeBlock():
    objects = []
    def __init__(self, key, label, isClosed, isRequired, attributes):
        self.key = key
        self.label = label
        self.isClosed = isClosed
        self.isRequired = isRequired
        self.attributes = attributes if attributes is not None else {}
        self.objects.append(self)
```

Once this is done, `add_attribute` could become:

```
def add_attribute_block(toybox = None, key = "" ):
    if toybox is not None:
        for obj in AttributeBlock.objects:
            if obj.key == key:
                toybox.attributes.append(obj)
                break
```

You could also use a mapping instead of a list for the class attribute:

```
class AttributeBlock():
    objects = {]
    def __init__(self, key, label, isClosed, isRequired, attributes):
        if key in self.objects:
            # raise a custom exception
        ...
        self.objects[key] = self
```

Then you can simply use:

```
def add_attribute_block(toybox = None, key = "" ):
    if toybox is not None:
        if key in AttributeBlock.objects:
            toybox.attributes.append(AttributeBlock.objects[key])
```

If you want to put a copy of the objects of the list in the `ToyBox`, you must change the creation method to allow to not put that copy in the global list. In that case, code would become:

```
class AttributeBlock():
    objects = {}
    dummy = {}
    def __init__(self, key, label, isClosed, isRequired,
             attributes, glob = None):
        if glob is None:
            glob = self.objects
        if key in glob:
            raise ValueError(str(key) + " already exists")
        self.key = key
        self.label = label
        self.isClosed = isClosed
        self.isRequired = isRequired
        self.attributes = attributes if attributes is not None else {}
        if glob is not self.dummy:
            glob[key] = self
    def copy(self):
        return AttributeBlock(self.key, self.label, self.isClosed,
                      self.isRequired, self.attributes[:],
                      self.dummy)
```

with a dummy class object that allow to not store the newly created object in any container, and an optional `glob` parameter that allows to store it in an external dict. Also notice the `copy` method that precisely uses `dummy`.

`add_attribute_block` becomes:

```
def add_attribute_block(toybox = None, key = "", glob = None ):
    if glob is None:
        glob = AttributeBlock.objects
    if toybox is not None:
        if key in glob:
            toybox.attributes.append(AttributeBlock.objects[key].copy())
```

using the copy method to store in the ToyBox, a copy of the original object that is not stored in the global container.

Comment: that is an interesting approach. is this good practice or should i create a more global variable that stores all the attribute blocks

Comment: are their any problems i should be aware of when doing this method? seems like a great solution

Comment: @JokerMartini: no general answer. If you want to keep track of each and every `AttributeBlock`, a class attribute is interesting. If you want instead to be able to have several independant lists (think of students in an university, what if you later want to deal with different universities...), you'd better have an external list and pass it in constructor. Like it often happens, it depends on the actual use case.

Comment: in my case i only need one list that contains all the attributeBlocks created. If that is the case then you'r solution would appear to work perfectly, correct?

Comment: I also noticed you are doing a straight append operation, wouldn't i need to do a deep copy?

Comment: @JokerMartini: Here again it depends on use case. Straight append is nice if you want to add the object reference and have it current if it is later changed. A copy is better if you want to take a *snapshot* that will remain unchanged if original object is modified. **I** can't know you real requirements :-)

Comment: fair enough, in my case i need each copy to be a new instance of the AttributeBlock

Comment: @JokerMartini: hmm... it is a corner case then, because you surely do not want those new instances to be added to the global container. I'll edit my answer soon to take this into account.

Comment: yeah i was thinking about making a global list continaing the initial list of AttributeBlocks, and then searching that for the matching key. If found it does a deepCopy and creates the new instance

Comment: @JokerMartini: I could write (and test) code allowing the use of copies (I assume that key and label are strings and that is... attributes are boolean and and such do not need to be copied)

Answer (score 1):

If you want to make sure the Attribute instance added to your ToyBox is a copy, the easiest way is to use the [standard copy module](https://docs.python.org/2/library/copy.html)

```
import copy
...
class ToyBox(object):
    ...
    def add_attribute(self, attribute):
        self.attributes.append(copy.deepcopy(attribute))
```

Comment: if that is true, how do i then setup the AttributeBlock objects so i can then create the function for adding?

Comment: Not sure I understand what you are asking. The copy.deepcopy() function does not require an object's class to be set up for it. copy.deepcopy(x) will make a copy of an object x no matter what class it is.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly, you want the each `ToyBox` instance to contain a list of `AttributeBlock` instances, checking no other such object with the 
same name is present in the list yet.

```
class AttributeBlock():
    def __init__(self, key): # demo, add the other parameters/attrs
        self.key = key
    def __str__(self):
        return self.key # add the other parameters/attrs

class ToyBox(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.attributes = []

    def add_attr(self, a):
        gen = (attr for attr in self.attributes if attr.key == a.key)
        try:
            next(gen)
        except StopIteration:
            self.attributes.append(a)

    def __str__(self):
        return ','.join(map(str,self.attributes))
```

So now we can do

```
>>> toy = ToyBox()
>>> toy.add_attr(AttributeBlock("Box"))
>>> toy.add_attr(AttributeBlock("Sphere"))
>>> toy.add_attr(AttributeBlock("Box"))
>>> print toy
Box,Sphere
```

As you notice, it makes sense to make the `add_attribute` function an instance method of `ToyBox`

BTW, in case the number of objects in the `attributes` list is large, it's better to use a dictionary:

```
class ToyBox(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.attributes = dict()

    def add_attr(self, a):
        if a.key not in self.attributes:
            self.attributes[a.key] = a

    def __str__(self):
        return ','.join(map(str,self.attributes.values()))
```

Note: in case you want to keep the order in which the objects are added, use an [OrderedDict](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.OrderedDict) instead

Comment: you are on the right track. When i create all my attritubeBlocks where do i store them. I only want to create them once when the tool first launches. Should i do what Serge Ballesta is suggesting below?

Comment: they are stored in the list of the ToyBox instance. See  the examples in my edit, no need to keep track of them in a variable

Answer (score 1):

Put all your attribute blocks in a list.

```
blocks = []

// add your AttributeBlocks to this list
blocks.append(block1)
blocks.append(block2)
blocks.append(block3)
```

Then it's easy.

```
def add_attribute_block(toybox, key):
    #loop over list of blocks and find the block with that key
    for block in blocks:
        if block.key == key:
            #only add it to the toybox if its not already in there
            if not any(key in l.key for l in toybox.attributes):
                toybox.attributes.append(block)
                break
```

Note:

`l.key for l in toybox.attributes` is a list comprehension and gives you a list of all keys.

`any(key in l.key for l in toybox.attributes)` returns `True` if `key` is in that list.